Detachable keyboard toggles on/off WIFI
I have a laptop (ASUS Zenbook Duo OLED 2024) which has a detachable keyboard and i installed kubuntu on it. Everything works fine but when i disconnect or connect the keyboard per USB to the laptop it turns off the WIFI. I have been sitting on this for hours now. Its not that big of a deal but gets quite annoying.
During my research i found this where it says that the button code for the WLAN is the same as the keyboard attach/detach events. So i ran xev which gave me these interesting outputs (interesting because of XF86WLAN):
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x5f7, subw 0x0, time 3017257, (369, 468), root(1720,1269),
    state 0x0, keycode 246 (keysym 0x1008ff95, XF86WLAN), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x5f7, subw 0x0, time 3017257, (369, 468), root(1720,1269),
    state 0x0, keycode 246 (keysym 0x1008ff95, XF86WLAN), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x5f7, subw 0x0, time 3017257, (369, 468), root(1720,1269),
    state 0x0, keycode 246 (keysym 0x1008ff95, XF86WLAN), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x5f7, subw 0x0, time 3017257, (369, 468), root(1720,1269),
    state 0x0, keycode 246 (keysym 0x1008ff95, XF86WLAN), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

So with this i tried to remap the keycode 246 with xmodmap to NoSymbol but that didn't work.
Then after some more digging someone mentioned the showkey command which i tried as well. But for some strange reason that command also gives me different keycodes for when i connect/dicsonnect my keyboard:
press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode 238 press
keycode 238 release

Also tried remapping that key but that also didn't work.
Then i tried my luck with ACPI, running acpi_listen and disconnecting my keyboard, which gave me this:
 0B3CBB35-E3C2- 000000ff 00000000
button/wlan WLAN 00000080 00000000 K

I then created a custom event handler in /etc/acpi/events/keyboard-handler:
event=button/wlan WLAN 00000080 00000000 K
action=/bin/true

I have read somewhere that action=/bin/true is just supposed to 'cancel' the event.
Then i restated acpi with sudo systemctl restart acpid and still no luck and I'm out of ideas.
Does anyone have an idea on how i can fix this?

If you know how to patch kernel modules, this should help.  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/platform?h=v6.12-rc2&id=9286dfd5735b9cceb6a14bdf15e13400ccb60fe7

Well I sadly don't. Guess that's my only option so I'll have to learn it then

You could download the 4 deb files for amd64 and install them to try the 6.11 kernel, Secure Boot will have to be disabled- https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.11/

You're troubleshooting your problem with xev the hard way. Read the first paragraph of this answer  for an easier command to use with xev

@karel I already tried the solution stated there but it sadly didn't work

It wasn't intended as an answer. It was only intended as a suggestion to make troubleshooting the problem easier by reducing the wall of text that you get from running xev to a few concise lines of filtered output.
